# Makefile error using flex

Tags: c++, c, makefile, flex-lexer

Trying to make a makefile that compiles cpp2html.c to produce cpp2html.o (I've done this). Next I have to run flex cppscanner.l to produce the file lex.yy.c from language cppscanner.l. (I've done this). Then I have to compile lex.yy.c to produce lex.yy.o. And finally link the .o files. (Done both)

```
cpp2html.o: cpp2html.c  
[TAB] gcc -g -DDEBUG -c cpp2html.c  //produces cpp2html.o

lex.yy.c: cppscanner.l  
[TAB] flex cppscanner.l -o lex.yy.c  //produces cppscanner language on lex.yy.c

lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c  
[TAB] gcc -g -c lex.yy.c             //produces lex.yy.o

cpp2html: cpp2html.o lex.yy.o   
[TAB] gcc -g -DDEBUG cpp2html.o lex.yy.o -o cpp2html //links the .o files
```

The error produced when I run it is "Your makefile does not build 'cpp2html' when invoked: gcc -g -DDEBUG -c cpp2html.c

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you really missing tabs in all the right places, or is that a copy and paste fail?

Comment: Copy and paste fail. My bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message suggests that there is a rule

```
cpp2html: cpp2html.c
    gcc -g -DDEBUG -c cpp2html.c
```

(with target missing the `.o`) somewhere. Double check that the rule is spelled as it is in your post, and that there is no other makefiles around.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my problem was my target file was at the bottom of the file. So I moved cpp2html: cpp2html.o lex.yy.o to the top of the file and cleared all .o's from the directory and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
gcc, when given no output file name, 
produces a file with the default name 
(I'm thinking a.out, but don't quote me) 
suggest:

BTW: the comment in a make file is started with '*' not '//'

BTW: perhaps there are no .h files, but if there are, they need to be 
     listed as dependencies and 
     if the header files are in the same directory then -I. needs to be appended
     to the compile statements, 
     otherwise replace the '.' with the path to the header files

BTW: perhaps there are no libraries being used,
     but if there are then 1) the path to the library needs to be appended to the 
     link operation via -Lpathtolibrary and -llibraryname

BTW: by using the built-in rules and the make file shortcut parameters
     (like $&, $< $> $@) a single rule can replace many similar rules)
     and creating some macros like: SRC := (wildcard:*.c) or YACC := (wildcard:*.l)
     and pattern replacement macros like:  
         OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)  $(YACC:.l=.o)
     a lot of code in a makefile does not need to be repetitive

* the 'all' target is first so user can just say 'make' with no parameters
* .PHONY lists those targets that will not produce a file with the same name
*        as the target
.PHONY: all
all: cpp2html

cpp2html.o: cpp2html.c  
[TAB] gcc -g -DDEBUG -c cpp2html.c  -o cpp2html.o 

lex.yy.c: cppscanner.l  
[TAB] flex cppscanner.l -o lex.yy.c  

lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c  
[TAB] gcc -g -c lex.yy.c  -o lex.yy.o          

* this does the link to produce the executable 
cpp2html: cpp2html.o lex.yy.o   
[TAB] gcc -g -DDEBUG cpp2html.o lex.yy.o -o cpp2html
```